# how to extract geotif file .tiff to csv

Tags: csv, raster, tiff

Is it possible to extract the .tiff file into .csv? Such as weather data, from http://worldclim.org/current, I want to get the value of each point, especially for the EU region. I tried using ArcTool conversion (raster to ASCII) but seems they did not separate the points by region.

Thanks

Comment: What do I have to click on that page to get a TIFF?

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I solved it using rasterToPoints. Thanks